# WCF CustomUserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I'm having an issue configuring WCF correctly for a security.  The below configuration simply fails to recognize that I'm trying to use a CustomUserNamePasswordValidator.  When I test the service, the Validator class is just ignored as though I've never configured anything. Can anyone spy something wrong in this configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior" name="SSAServices.SelfServiceAdvertiserService">
    <endpoint address="/2.4/SelfServiceAdvertiserService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SSAServiceContracts.Two_Four.ISelfServiceAdvertiserService" bindingConfiguration="serviceBinding" />
 </service>
    </services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="serviceBinding" >
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
    <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceAuthenticationBase, SSAServices" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the service work with this configuration?

Comment: The service does work.  It simply ignores the configuration.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that I'm using the VS Development Server?

Answer (score 3):

I think the cuase of the problem is here:

```
customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceAuthenticationBase, SSAServices"
```

You should declare your type with its namespace and class name like this:

```
customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SSAServices.ServiceAuthenticationBase, SSAServices"
```

customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="type, assembly"

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Impluse is probably on the right track. The ServiceAuthenticationBase  class will likely be in a root namespace and it needs to be fully qualified in the customUserNamePasswordValidatorType attribute value. The config seems right when checked against the info in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I did try that.  In fact, I can put anything ("blahType") in place of those values and I get no failures whatsoever.

Comment: Only thing I would try is to create a simple WCF service from scratch and configure it with the custom validator as the link outlines.  That's a way of isolating the configuration required for validation from your current service config.

Answer (score 2):

OK I asked a question to see if this binding works - since I doubted - but I though I might as well post my answer as I cannot see how this can work.

Message security requires encryption and for this to happen you also need negotiation. So you need to setup a X509 certificate for your service in the beahviour section:

```
                     <serviceCredentials>
                            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                 storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="type, assembly" />
                     </serviceCredentials>
```

Also make sure you turn on negotiation as well:

```
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
```

Comment: I've tried to set this up and it still seems to be bypassing the configuration.  I've got it setup exactly how you've stated and when I query the ServiceSecurityContext I'm seeing that it's authenticating based on anonymous access.  I'm not sure what's wrong here.  I've read several examples and none of them really show a different config from what I'm using.